# Problema Apache con IP la web no funciona siempre, pero con localhost si funciona

Tags: webservice, apache, xampp

Tengo un problema cada X tiempo el servidor web deja de responder a la IP por ejemplo si accedemos a el mediante la URL :
http://192.168.1.24:8059 <- Esto deja de funcionar, pero si accedes por :
http://localhost:8059 <- esto funciona, es la misma máquina el, mismo servidor...

No es reproducible, el fallo puede dar al minuto como tirarse semanas sin dar problemas, es algo completamente arbitrario que veo imposible de reproducir.

La única solución que he encontrado es reiniciar el webservice.

Pero no encuentro el motivo de porque deja de funcionar la IP

Evidentemente es imposible estar checkeando la URL a cada instante, por lo que me he creado una tarea programada que cada minuto consulta http://192.168.1.24:8059/ping.php si da status = 200 no se hace nada si da otro estado, reinicio automáticamente el webservice.

Pero evidentemente esto es como matar moscas a cañonazos.

El servidor es UwAmp, pero también tengo el mismo problema con el Xampp, lo que traslada el problema al Apache y algo que hace que el httpd.exe quede bloqueado para IP....

Comment: Tú dices que : `si da status = 200 no se hace nada si da otro estado`, cual o cuales serían esos otros status que te da ?

Comment: Te lo dije en un comentario abajo, te lo repito nuevamente. No das antecedentes necesarios para realizar una respuesta. Verifica logs y pon mayores antecedentes. Como tu pregunta es imposible de responder, votaré para cerrarla

Comment: Lo siento soy nuevo en esto ni vi estos comentarios...

Comment: a ver si puedo detallar:
1.- Montas apache. 
2.- Funciona.  
3.- X motivo deja de responder a la IP del servidor . 
Toda la configuración es correcta 
El apache esta corriendo, si vas al servidor y pones localhost funciona 
la única forma de que vuelva a funcionar es reiniciando. 

Lo del estado 200 es porque solicito una página que siempre da 200, siempre funciona si da un 400  o lo que sea lo reinicia.

Cuando ocurre da un timeout porque no se puede acceder desde fuera del servidor ni desde el propio servidor poniendo la IP, pero insisto apache funciona igual que localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por pasos como dice Jack el destripador. Y cito:

> si accedemos a el mediante la URL : http://192.168.1.24:8059 <- Esto deja de funcionar, pero si accedes por : http://localhost:8059 <- esto funciona, es la misma máquina el, mismo servidor...

Cuando entras por IP con http://192.168.1.24:8059 casi siempre es porque entras desde otra maquina. Ahora, http://localhost:8059 siempre te funcionará pues estas en local.

Pero puedes solucionar esto de dos formas (seguramente hay mas)

Puedes usar el nombre de tu "servidor" o PC servidor, según sea el caso. En lugar de entrar por http://192.168.1.24:8059 entra por **http://serverName:8059/tuSystem**. De esta forma tengo varios sistemas en varias empresas y nunca han dado falla. Eso si, cuando ya tienes un sistema en producción lo mejor, por temas de seguridad, es no usar un paquete de desarrollo como XAMPP u otros, sino usar los módulos separados de Apache, PHP, MySQL, etc...

La otra forma, un poco mas trabajosa dependiendo el numero de maquinas de tu red, es crear un virtual host en tu server y entrar a ese host virtual desde los clientes.

Te vas al archivo **httpd-vhosts.conf**, que maneja los virtual host de apache, en XAMPP por ejemplo, está en `apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` y creamos el virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:8059>
  DocumentRoot "C:\tuServer\tuSystem"
  ServerName tuSystem.test
  <Directory "C:\tuServer\tuSystem">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Luego vas a cada cliente de tu red, abres el **notepad** como administrador y abres el archivo host de la ruta `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` y escribes al final lo siguiente

```
# virtualhost
192.168.1.24    tuSystem.test
```

Y ya puedes entrar desde los clientes a la dirección **http://tuSystem.test/**

*PD: en lugar de **.test** puedes usar otra extensión.*

Comment: Es difícil explicar la situación... lo que quiero decir yo tengo las urls:

Comment: - http://dominio.com:8059 
- http://192.168.1.24:8059 
Y eso funciona perfectamente, y sin previo aviso deja de funcionar 

Lo primero que compruebas es en el servidor a poner  :
- http://192.168.1.24:8059 
Y sigue sin funcionar, reiniciaba y todo volvía a funcionar X tiempo hasta que volvía. 

Aquí lo raro es que en el mismo servidor donde esta el apache cuando deja de funcionar si pones la IP no va pero si pones LOCALHOST si funciona. 

No encuentro la razón porque se ha tirado semanas funcionando.

Comment: El tema de virtual host, no usar herramientas de desarrollo, lo se. Es como decirlo ¿porqué el servidor deja de funcionar?,  llamándolo tanto desde el exterior como desde la propia máquina, pero si pones localhost funciona.

Comment: @GustavoMoránChacón Es difícil, pero tú tampoco brindas muchos antecedentes. Yo te realicé una pregunta y no la respondiste. Toda solicitud arroja una respuesta, incluso cuando la IP no existe. Depende de lo que te retorne puedes determinar si el problema es tu aplicación, el servidor web o un problema de red, porque hasta puede ser que alguien se conecte y ocupe la misma ip del servidor. Pero básicamente dices "a veces me funciona y otras no"